# Do you need a permission to get the Locale of a device?

Tags: android, android-manifest, locale, android-permissions

I am working on an application, which has to adapt considering the country which the smartphone uses as Location.

Do I need to declare any permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml** like I do for network connection:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: You need location permission if you want to access user's location using your App

Comment: That makes sense, but I thought Locale isn't the real location, but only the one which is set by the users as their "Region". Something like "en_US" or so. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: For that no location is required, there are other ways to get user's location without using actual location, you can get location of a user using IP address, but it is ethical to notify the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need permission for getting the current locale. You just use:

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it the same as `Locale.getDefault()` ?

Comment: No. getDefault returns the current value of the default locale for the specified Category for this instance of the Java Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1):

No.You don't need to declare permission in manifest.